# Sending a JSON in batches

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have some doubts on how to perform some tasks I use jackson to create a JSON, after I encrypt I need to do it sent to a service that will consume this JSON, the problem is that the file size (physical) is 3,571 KB and I need to send in batches of at most 1,000KB 
each one, as I am newcomer with springBoot and web in general I saw that I have to do something called pagination, is that it?

I have a Dto (students) a class manager where I make access to the database that returns me a list of students
Then I create json, step to base 64 to finally configure the header and make the request

```
  studentList= StudantManager.getAllStudants(con);
    int sizeRecords = studentList.size();
    try {
       students= useful.convertToJson(studentList);
       studentsWithSecurity = useful.securityJson(students);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
    }
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "myRestService";
    HttpHeaders headers;
    headers=getHeaders(sizeRecords,students);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(studentsWithSecurity, headers);
    String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
```

Taking advantage of my current code, how can I create a solution that solves the upload problem that I mentioned above?